# Error when trying to use an object as an attribute of a class

Tags: c++, oop

I have several classes in my program, but I am focusing on the classes Loan and LibraryItem for the moment. I intend to use a LibraryItem object as an attribute of the Loan class. When I attempt to do so, I get an error.

I have looked at similar examples in books and online, but could not find teh problem.

LibraryItem.h

```
#ifndef LIBRARYITEM_H
#define LIBRARYITEM_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class LibraryItem
{
    public:
        LibraryItem(int id, string t, int y);
        int getID();
        string getTitle();
        int getYear();
        void setCheckedOut(bool c);
        bool isCheckedOut();

    private:
        int itemID;
        string title;
        int year;
        bool checkedOut;
};

#endif // LIBRARYITEM_H LibraryItem(int id, string t, int y);
```

LibraryItem.cpp

```
#include "LibraryItem.h"

LibraryItem::LibraryItem(int id, string t, int y)
{
    //ctor
    itemID = id;    title = t;  year = y;
    checkedOut = false;
}

int LibraryItem::getID()
{
    return itemID;
}

string LibraryItem::getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

int LibraryItem::getYear()
{
    return year;
}

void LibraryItem::setCheckedOut(bool c)
{
    checkedOut = c;
}

bool LibraryItem::isCheckedOut()
{
    return checkedOut;
}
```

Loan.h

```
#ifndef LOAN_H
#define LOAN_H

#include <string>

#include "LibraryItem.h"

using namespace std;

class Loan
{
    public:
        Loan();
        Loan(int id, LibraryItem i, string bdate, string ddate);

        int getID();
        string getBorrowDate();
        string getDueDate();
        LibraryItem getItem();

    private:
        int loanID;
        string borrowDate;
        string dueDate;
        LibraryItem item;
};

#endif // LOAN_H
```

Loan.cpp

```
#include "Loan.h"

Loan::Loan()
{

}

Loan::Loan(int id, LibraryItem i, string bdate, string ddate)
{
    loanID = id;    borrowDate = bdate; dueDate = ddate;
    item = i;
}

int Loan::getID()
{
    return loanID;
}

string Loan::getBorrowDate()
{
    return borrowDate;
}

string Loan::getDueDate()
{
    return dueDate;
}

LibraryItem Loan::getItem()
{
    return item;
}  //ctor
```

On line 3 of Loan.cpp, I come up with the following error:
error: no matching function for call to 'LibraryItem::LibraryItem()'

Comment: The error is telling you that you're missing a default constructor for LibraryItem. By defining your own constructor, you disabled the default. Declare this in the header: `LibraryItem() = default;`

Comment: Yes, the following works:        Loan(int id, LibraryItem i, string bdate, string ddate):loanID(id), borrowDate(bdate), dueDate(ddate), item(i){} Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Loan` constructor needs to default-initialise its `item` before entering the body, but `LibraryItem` does not have a default constructor.

Use an initialiser list for member initialisation:

```
Loan::Loan(int id, LibraryItem i, string bdate, string ddate)
  : loanID(id),
    borrowDate(bdate),
    dueDate(ddate),
    item(i)  
{
    // Intentionally empty.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a definition for a constructor

```
LibraryItem::LibraryItem(int id, string t, int y)
```

But you never declared this function in your class definition. Add this line inside your class definition

```
LibraryItem(int id, string t, int y);
```

Comment: I checked my code and that line was actually there, I fixed the code above.